# Fender California Series Newporter guitar preamp built-in tuner

Tags: guitar, tuner

I am a new player and I have an electro-acoustic Fender Newporter guitar. This guitar is from what they call their California series and they are all equipped with a built-in preamp with a tuner from Fishman. It looks like this:

[image]

I only play acoustically for now, I don't have an amp or anything. I have a regular tuner, but I was wondering if this on-board tuner can be used to tune the guitar when playing acoustically? I wasn't able to figure out how to turn it on. I guess it only comes on when the guitar is connected to an amp? Since I don't have one, I can't verify this.

Does anyone have a guitar from this series or know about them to be able to tell me whether the tuner can be used when the guitar is unplugged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer by myself. It's not very visible on the photo I've posted in the question, but there's two icons by the sides of the display. One is a fork icon and the other looks like an empty set icon. These are both physical buttons. They are kinda mushy and I first thought I was breaking the screen by pressing on them, but they are. Not sure what the latter does, but long-pressing the former turns the tuner on or off.

Comment: When you say empty set you mean [ ] or something else. I can’t tell from the image.

Comment: probably a low-battery icon.

Comment: Scratch that, it is phase inversion. See page 6 ( https://www.fmicassets.com/Damroot/Original/10001/OM_leg_acougtr_Fender_Paramount_Owner's_Manual_2015.pdf )